# Babel 7 not transforming builtin subclasses properly

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, browserify, ecmascript-5

Babel version: 7.6.0

I am working on [a JavaScript widget](https://github.com/SylvainBigonneau/edtf-datepicker) meant for browser use, but it depends on a library built for NodeJS ( [edtf.js](https://github.com/inukshuk/edtf.js/) ). Particularly, it extends the `Date` builtin in [this file](https://github.com/inukshuk/edtf.js/blob/master/src/date.js).

So far, it seems to work on all modern browsers I have tested it with. But to make sure it is bulletproof to older ones, I thought of Babelifying the edtf library. Here is the browserify configuration from [my Gruntfile.js](https://github.com/SylvainBigonneau/edtf-datepicker/blob/babelify/Gruntfile.js):

```js
browserify: {
  development: {
    src: [
      "node_modules/edtf/index.js"
    ],
    dest: './dist/js/edtf.js',
    options: {
      browserifyOptions: { standalone: 'edtf' },
      transform: [["babelify", {
        "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"], "plugins": [["@babel/transform-runtime", {"helpers": false}]]
      }]]
    }
  }
},
```

After a lot of tinkering, this configuration at least does not trigger any error when the resulting javascript file is loaded on the page, but as soon as I start using the library it breaks with this error:

```
edtf.js:3040 Uncaught TypeError: this is not a Date object.
   at Date.getUTCFullYear (<anonymous>)
   at Date.get (edtf.js:3040)
   at Date.toEDTF (edtf.js:2960)
   at Date.value (edtf.js:5696)
   at new Date (<anonymous>)
```

A [previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37609218/1439597) correctly points out that **builtin subclasses are only partially supported by Babel**, [according to their documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#subclassable-built-ins), and suggests using the [transform-builtin-extend](https://github.com/loganfsmyth/babel-plugin-transform-builtin-extend) plugin, which is sadly unmaintained for 2 years and only suits Babel 6.

Shouldn't the [transform classes](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-classes) work for that? I tried including it in my config, but it changed strictly nothing.

Anyway, if anyone has any advice on how to move forward, [here is the github branch to try it for yourself](https://github.com/SylvainBigonneau/edtf-datepicker/tree/babelify), simply run `npm install`, `npm run build` and open the `index.html` file in your browser. Any recommendation is welcomed: I am not married to the Babel idea, but I want to make sure that I can safely use this edtf library and have it working on the majority of browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that you *can't* subclass `Date` using only ES5 and earlier features. It simply doesn't work (like `Error` and `Array`).

If you need to use your code transpiled to ES5 or earlier, you'll have to modify your class so it doesn't try to subclass `Date`. (For instance, use a `Date` instance as a member instead and forward the method calls on...)

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that option! Only issue I have with this (aside from the additional headscratching it will take) is that it would mean forking the original edtf.js project. I was hoping to rely on it strictly as a dependency to benefit from future changes. And I don't think it is anywhere in the maintainers intentions to make the library ES5 compatible. :(

Comment: @SylvainB - Ugh, that *is* too bad. :-|

Comment: So I modified the class to manipulate a private `Date` member as you suggested, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39427251/1439597) and it seems to be working just like a charm! Now I'm wondering: shouldn't there be a way to tell Babel to do just that, automatically?

Comment: @SylvainB - Cool! I suspect it's just not a big enough issue for people. It's also fairly imperfect, since of course `x instanceof Date` will be false (though one hopes that there aren't `instanceof` checks in a lot of code...). (Come to think of it, there's also the issue that Date defaults to `toString` when being converted to primitive without a type hint, but your class will default to `valueOf` in that case. And you can't fix that without an ES2015 feature [`Symbol.toPrimitive`]. *sigh*) It would certainly be possible to write a transform plugin to do that.

Comment: Hahah, yeah I might end up doing that transform plugin... those couple issues you brought up about `instanceof` and `toString` do not seem to impact my modest widget, so it's a bummer that I couldn't find something less extreme.